# Could arc reactors eventually be real?

Tags: energy

Could [arc reactors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_reactor) eventually be real? I have wondered about this, there is not much about it online. If they could how would they work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are efforts to build small nuclear reactors which we can use in our homes.
The effort is to use LENR technology.
As for whether arc reactors can *eventually* be real, then we could wait for engineering innovations and scientific discoveries under the condition that

> “All we really need is that one bit of irrefutable, reproducible proof
>   that we have a system that works,” Zawodny said.

The short answer is **We don't know yet.**

Readings:
The nuclear reactor in your basement
http://climate.nasa.gov/news/864

NASA’s cold fusion tech could put a nuclear reactor in every home, car, and plane
http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/149090-nasas-cold-fusion-tech-could-put-a-nuclear-reactor-in-every-home-car-and-plane

Answer (score 1):

Well, **no**, such a thing cannot be made because it is a fictional concept. You ask "how would they work," and the reason you can't find any information is that arc reactors are [plot devices](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotDevice) and nothing more. Science will never invent a way to harness energy from writers' imaginations (or lack thereof) the same way the arc reactor can.

If you want a more scientific answer, you have to be more specific with what you are looking for. Do you want a small supply of useful energy? We have those; they're called batteries. Do you want a power supply that glows? One that runs on fission? Fusion? Higgs bosons? Those are valid questions. Of course you can never have a device that runs on nothing, producing power without any fuel.